# Accessing instance method of a different class with current object

Tags: ruby, oop

From the book **Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby**, by Sandi Metz:

```
class Gear
 attr_reader :chainring, :cog, :rim, :tire
 def initialize(chainring, cog, rim, tire)
  @chainring = chainring
  @cog = cog
  @rim = rim
  @tire = tire
 end

  def ratio
   chainring / cog.to_f
  end    
 def gear_inches
  ratio * Wheel.new(rim, tire).diameter #line number 11
 end
 # ...
end

class Wheel
 attr_reader :rim, :tire
 def initialize(rim, tire)
  @rim = rim
  @tire = tire
 end

 def diameter
  rim + (tire * 2)
 end
 # ...
 end

 Gear.new(52, 11, 26, 1.5).gear_inches
```

> The immediate, obvious consequence of this reference is that if the name of the
> Wheel class changes, Gear’s gear_inches method must also change.
> On the face of it this dependency seems innocuous. After all, if a Gear needs to
> talk to a Wheel, something, somewhere, must create a new instance of the Wheel
> class. If Gear itself knows the name of the Wheel class, the code in Gear must be
> altered if Wheel’s name changes.

> In truth, dealing with the name change is a relatively minor issue. You likely have
> a tool that allows you to do a global find/replace within a project. If Wheel’s name
> changes to Wheely, finding and fixing all of the references isn’t that hard. However,
> the fact that line 11 above must change if the name of the Wheel class changes is the
> least of the problems with this code. A deeper problem exists that is far less visible but
> significantly more destructive.

> **When Gear hard-codes a reference to Wheel deep inside its gear_inches
> method, it is explicitly declaring that it is only willing to calculate gear inches for
> instances of Wheel. Gear refuses to collaborate with any other kind of object, even if
> that object has a diameter and uses gears.**

> If your application expands to include objects such as disks or cylinders and you
> need to know the gear inches of gears which use them, you cannot. Despite the fact
> that disks and cylinders naturally have a diameter you can never calculate their gear
> inches because Gear is stuck to Wheel.

I couldn't get wrap my head around the paragraph which is made bold. How can disk and cylinder objects access the method **gear_inches**, since gear_inches is an instance method of class Gear.(Sending gear_inches message to Disk and Cylinder)

Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can disk and cylinder objects access the method `gear_inches`, since `gear_inches` is an instance method of class `Gear`.

The text doesn't say that disk or cylinder are supposed to call `gear_inches`. Quite the opposite: `gear_inches` needs a *diameter* to calculate its return value. Right now, it gets that diameter from a `Wheel` instance that it creates on its own.

However, hard-coding `Wheel.new(...)` into the method creates a coupling between `Gear` and `Wheel`. To loosen this coupling, you could for example *pass* the wheel instance to `Gear`'s initializer. Which is exactly what Sandi shows in the next example:

> POODR, page 41:
>
> ```
> class Gear
>   attr_reader :chainring, :cog, :wheel
>   def initialize(chainring, cog, wheel)
>     @chainring = chainring
>     @cog       = cog
>     @wheel     = wheel
>   end
>
>   def gear_inches
>     ratio * wheel.diameter
>   end
> # ...
> end
>
> # Gear expects a 'Duck' that knows 'diameter'
> Gear.new(52, 11, Wheel.new(26, 1.5)).gear_inches
> ```

*"a 'Duck' that knows 'diameter'"* means that `wheel` doesn't have to be an actual wheel (an instance of the `Wheel` class). Instead, it could be any object that responds to `diameter`, like for example a (hypothetical) disk or cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a more hypothetical scenario, since what it describes is clearly not coded in the example you provided.

First, note that the `Wheel` instance isn't accessing any methods in the `Gear` class in this case. The other way around, `Gear` is accessing methods from a `Wheel` instance.

Second, think how a `Gear` would calculate a diameter for a potentially different type. Now using `Wheel.new(...)` wouldn't make any sense! What you could do, is pass the object that has a `diameter` method as a parameter, and call that method inside of `gear_inches`:

```rb
# One possible implementation
def gear_inches(object_with_diameter)
  ratio * object_with_diameter.diameter
end
```

Now the `gear_inches` depend on what type of object is being passed, and isn't tied to `Wheel`.